# How to route two different audiences through one web page?

Tags: navigation, audience

I have 2 audiences on one product(services) page: some of the services available only for "rich" people, and some for poor. Most visitors are of course poor people. So how would you solve this? How to navigate these audiences without actually telling them if they are poor or rich? We can not use descriptors like "premium" and stuff because of the service specifics.

Comment: Whats the nature of website? Ecommerce?Also how to you identify the people status at first place if they are rich or poor? do you capture the status during when the visitor signup? If you know the visitor status poor/rich during the session start time, you can store the status into the cookie and can do a cookie based marketing, there by page acts dynamic enough to show targeted data to the visitor.

Comment: The nature of website is consulting services. We don't know who is who:( The point is to make a page where the member of each segment will find her way.

Comment: Could you give some insight into why users are "segregated" like this?

Comment: We have totally different service portfolio available to each group

Comment: Ok, may be you can provide two different buttons on the landing page, to attract and target poor and rich. So they divert themselves.. or put a short survey form about their interests on the landing page which shouldnt be too annoying and accordingly you can show the targeted content?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the businesses try to convert free users into premium, which is their primary goal.

**List all services with benefits.** Let the user decide what they want and if they can pay. This way you can pursue them to buy services, if they like them rather than hiding. ( for reference: You may check any hosting site )

Another possible solution could be, let them try all the services with limited feature for limited time period and ask to upgrade if they like.

Answer (score 0):

You can categorize services by how expensive they are. Perhaps the categories could simply be “expensive” and “modest” or perhaps you could have a range of categories such as $, $$, $$$, $$$$, and $$$$$.

If you have a lot of categories, you could add functionality for the user to filter by category. Ie. Allowing them to check off $$ and $$$ if that is what they’re interested in.

Answer (score -1):

This can be handled through branding and colours. I once did some work for a financial institution whose logo is royal blue with a hint of yellow. However, once high-net worth individuals log on to the website, the logo changes to gold.

Comment: Can you elaborate? the best answers on this site tend to have some more substance and something beyond anecdotal data to support them--these are more useful answers to more people. I think you've got something here if you work on it a bit more!

Comment: there's no log in:(

Answer (score -1):

How do you know they are "poor". Wha does "poor" mean anyway? Sounds like an extreme categorisation. Do they not own devices? They dont ahve money but are on the website? So what is their purpose?

In any case when you have 2 categories of users you can always base designs off Motivations or Behaviours rather than demographics. Again, I think your terminology needs looking into.